# Is browser extension message passing private?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, sendmessage, safari-extension

The title says it all - is message passing between an extension background page and an injected script that runs on the website being visited totally private?

For example, on chrome you have chrome.runtime.sendMessage() and chrome.tabs.sendMessage() as documented in https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging

Do I need my message data to be unique in case another extension happens to use the same name for fields in the data?

If I was using window.postMessage() I would make sure my message was unique, do I need to do the same in the extension message passing?

Thanks ...

Comment: Yes, it's private.

Comment: _bold_Thanks!_bold_